# setLayoutParams doesn't work on ToggleButton

Tags: android

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/master_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

        </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In code, I add some buttons to the table layout which will populate added buttons by 4 per row:

To add buttons:

```
TableRow row = createTableRow();
row.addView(createToggleButton(R.id.button1, getResources().getText(R.string.button1)));
row.addView(createToggleButton(R.id.button2, getResources().getText(R.string.button2)));
row.addView(createToggleButton(R.id.button3, getResources().getText(R.string.button3)));
row.addView(createToggleButton(R.id.button4, getResources().getText(R.string.button4)));

TableLayout parent = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.master_table);
parent.addView(firstRow);
```

Original version of createToggleButton() method:

```
private ToggleButton createToggleButton(int id, CharSequence text) {
    ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(this);
    button.setId(id);
    button.setTextOff(text);
    button.setTextOn(text);
    button.setChecked(false);
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button, this.getTheme()));
    button.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_color));

    return button;
}
```

This work, my buttons are added to the view. But when I try to apply LayoutParams as below:

```
private ToggleButton createToggleButton(int id, CharSequence text) {
    ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(this);
    // This line cause the button disappeared !?
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    button.setId(id);
    button.setTextOff(text);
    button.setTextOn(text);
    button.setChecked(false);
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button, this.getTheme()));
    button.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.button_color));

    return button;
}
```

My buttons no longer appear on the view even though there are no error occurred. What happens here?

Comment: If you rollback to use your "original version" it really works? I doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be caused by the width of TableRow and its ToggleButton children are interdependent.

set LayoutParam for TableRow

```
row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Also change the Layout of ToggleButton to this

```
button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is working now. Thank you for your help.